# Prove that $f$ is continuous at a point $x_n$ if and only if the sequence $\{y_n\}=\{f(x_n)\}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $f$ be a mapping of one metric space $X$ into another metric space $Y$.Prove that $f$ is continuous at a point $x_n$ if and only if the sequence $\{y_n\}=\{f(x_n)\}$ converges to $y=f(x_i)$ whenever the sequence $\{x_n\}$ converges to $x_n$.

### My attempt:

(Might be a duplicate but I am specifically asking about my proof for my question)

Let $f:(X,d_X) \rightarrow (Y,d_y)$ be the map between $X$ and $Y$. To show that $f$ is continuous at a point, say $x_\in X$, we have to show that for all open ball $B_f(x)(\epsilon)$ with radius $\epsilon$ on $f(x)$, there exists an open ball $B_x(\delta)$ of radius $x$ and $f(B_x(\delta))$ is a contained in $B_f(x)(\epsilon)$.

Suppose $f$ is not continuous at $x$ but it has the property of limit of sequences. Then,  $\epsilon>0$ exists for every $\delta >0$ such that $d_X(x,y)<\delta$ for poiunts $x$ and $y$. But $d_Y(f(x),f(y))>\epsilon$ so we can make a sequence of $\delta_i$ that convergers to $0$ and there is a $y_i$ such that $d_X(x,y_i)<\delta_i$ which convergers to $x$ but not $f(x)$.

Now say $f$ is continuous and suppose $x_n$ convergers to $x$. $f$ is continuous so there is an open ball such that $d_X(x,y)<\delta$ of radius delta $\Rightarrow d_Y(f(x),f(y))<\epsilon$ and $x_n$ exists in $\delta$ of center $x$ and the image exists in $\epsilon$ ball of center $f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Two notes if you are turning this in: in the first proof, what you want is to explicitly construct a sequence converging to $x$, but whose image does not converge to $y$. Try taking your deltas to be $1/n$. Then for each $B_X(x,1/n)$, there is a point in $f(B_X(x,1/n))$, call it $y_n$, such that $d_Y(y,y_n)\ge\epsilon$.

In the second part, you might want to explicitly say that there is an integer $N$ such that $d_Y(y,y_n)<\epsilon$ if $n\ge N$.